# Can I install Debian Linux on a rooted Android device

Tags: linux, debian, android

Most of you know you should unlock bootloader to root android device, and unlocking the bootloader give you the ability to install other ROM "as far as I know".

So is it possible to go crazy and install Linux Debian on android device, if yes what are the things that I should keep in mind before and while doing it.

Comment: Note that you probably can, but it may not be fully functional as a phone.  That may or may not be important to you.

Comment: i know this is late but can you name common problems that i may face why installing different rom.

Comment: A lot of drivers for phones are not shipped in a standard Linux kernel, only in the stock Android or vendor kernels, and as a result, you may or may not have drivers for things like the GPU, the cell radio, or other peripherals.

Comment: how about wireless interface should i install a another driver, so if i find a way to ssh to it can i install the drivers ?

Comment: [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it requires some knowledge in Linux and Android. There are a few devices that can be used to install a Debian version, most of the time devices that can be used for Ethical Hacking.

Check following links for further reading:

[Running Debian Linux on Android device natively](https://medium.com/@quantvc/running-debian-on-android-device-natively-73545c9b0757)

[Pwnie Express](https://github.com/pwnieexpress)

Comment: not gonna use it for hacking just want phone shaped pihole, but thanks for the answer.